# Get CPU preemption count on Linux

Tags: linux

Is it possible to get this counter via procfs/sysfs? That is how many times CPU preempted any active task. Per process value is also OK. 
`Linux pve-index 4.15.18-5-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-24 (Thu, 13 Sep 2018 09:15:10 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean non-voluntary context switches, then there is at least couple files under `/proc`:

```
# cat /proc/61115/status | grep ctxt_switches
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        6511
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     143

# cat /proc/61115/sched
bash (61115, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
...
nr_switches                                  :                 6594
nr_voluntary_switches                        :                 6451
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                  143
```

Just replace number 61115 with the wanted pid.

Comment: I launched single process(lost of CPUs resources are available)  and this counters was increasing every second. It seems to me its just CPU time slices for the current process

Comment: So I am intrested in the following scenario: my process is preempted and new rescheduled process is another one, not mine